# SQL Server dynamic selection of output column

Tags: sql-server

Just started using SQL Server. This seems like it should be super easy, but haven't found an answer yet.

Trying to go from this:

```
id  fruit  value
1   apple   10
2   orange  a
3   orange  b
4   apple   20
5   apple   30
```

To this:

```
fruit  quantitative qualitative
apple   10  NULL
orange  NULL    a
orange  NULL    b
apple   20  NULL
apple   30  NULL
```

Something like...

- If apple -> put the value in column 2, column 3 = NULL
- If orange -> put the value in column 3, column 2 = NULL

Thank you!

Comment: The answers will tell you how to do this. I would advise a different design, putting qualitive properties and quantitive properties in their own columns to begin with.  Datatypes are your friends.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select 
fruit,
case when fruit = 'apple' then value else null end as quantitative,
case when fruit = 'orange' then value else null end as qualitative
from mytable
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/45c80/1)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ISNUMERIC` and `CASE`:

```
SELECT fruit,
       quantitative=CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(value)=1 THEN value ELSE NULL END,
       qualitative=CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(value)=0 THEN value ELSE NULL END
FROM dbo.Fruits
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6f476/2/0)

```
FRUIT   QUANTITATIVE    QUALITATIVE
apple   10              (null)
orange  (null)           a
orange  (null)           b
apple   20              (null)
apple   30              (null)
```

Comment: I would like it to use the column name 'fruit' in the logic instead of the data type in the column 'value'.